# VB.NET/MS ACCESS Display data from query

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a textbox that I need to run this query when the value changes for the textbox.

```
Private Sub tbStudentID2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbStudentID2.TextChanged
    mySql = "SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData"
    ConnDB()
    myCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySql, myConnection)
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myRead = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    Do While myRead.Read = True
        tbDays.Text = myRead(0).ToString()
    Loop
End Sub
```

86 is display no matter which record I choose.  I think it is just retrieving the first record in the in the table.

I want to display the number of days since a student has tested by subtracting DateofRank from currentDate.  I am open to other ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: `Do While myRead.Read = True` `tbDays.Text = myRead(0).ToString()`, doesn't it loop over all the records and overwrite the TextBox every time, resulting in only displaying the last record? `"no matter which record I choose"` I don't see any use of `tbStudentID2` so maybe you want to include a WHERE clause to filter on that student?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print(tbDays.Text)` inside your loop after you set the Text(), and have a look at your output window, will give you some insight as to what's going on

Comment: I did the Debug.Print(tbDays.Text) and it appears like this in the output window:
52
52
52
52
52
3
86
86
86
86
86

So it looks like it is processing the DATEDIFF but on all of the entries in the table/column and just keeps adding 86 to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of the TextBox with each pass.  Make sure Multiline is set to true and try the following.

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder
Do While myRead.Read = True
    'tbDays.Text &= myRead(0).ToString()  Note the &= to keep concatenating the string.
    builder.Append(myRead(0).ToString())
Loop
tbDays.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to introduce a condition ~ `WHERE ID = tbStudentID2.Text`

```vb
Private Sub tbStudentID2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbStudentID2.TextChanged
    Dim id As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(tbStudentID2.Text, id) Then
        mySql = $"SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData WHERE id={id}"
        ConnDB()
        myCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySql, myConnection)
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myRead = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Do While myRead.Read()
            tbDays.Text = myRead(0).ToString()
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

I guess your ID is an Integer. If that's the case, this will work, and is immune to SQL injection. I validated your input. Do you want to query when a typo happens? Also, do you really want to query, when typing 12345, ID=1, ID=12, ID=123, ID=1234, and ID=12345? Maybe it's not typed in - then it's OK.

You may need to change the condition to the appropriate field name i.e. `[StudentData].[ID]`?

Also, this will always result in the *last* match in the table. If you don't expect more than one match, then you can just take the first. You could eliminate the `Do While` loop.

I see some other issues such as disposable objects not being disposed. You shouldn't keep your database connection open when you aren't using it. The objects which should be disposed of immediately, in order, are `myRead`, `myCommand`, and `myConnection`. This is easily handled by declaring them with the `Using` keyword, in the reverse order of my list. `ConnDB()` could return your connection in that case.

Comment: When I tried WHERE ID = tbStudentID2.Text I got this error:  unhandled exception type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'  Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

When I tried WHERE id={id} I got:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Malformed GUID in query expression 'id={id}'.

Also thanks for the additional input.  I plan to make those changes.

Comment: does your query start with a `$` as mine does? `$"SELECT `. It's just string interpolation. You can also concatenate your string the traditional way if you like `mySql = "SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData WHERE id=" & id.ToString()`. And just to confirm, is the field in the database actually called `id`? and is it numeric?

Comment: It would help if you could create an actual SQL query prior to this step. The one in your question is not going to work. Fix that first. Then it will be trivial to put it into vb.net

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed with help from a post on an another site. I do have one question though. If I comment out the first db connection - ConnDB() I get an error. Why does it need two connection to work? It makes a connection in the using command. I had setup a data table from a class I wrote to make a connection and set it up so I declare Private Access As New DBControl at the top and I can add parameters and do my additions and edits that way. I didn't know how to make that work with the existing connection to the Access DBControl so I just did another connection. Not the best but I am a beginner and don't know how to do things with more efficiency yet.

```
Private Sub tbStudentID2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbStudentID2.TextChanged
    mySql = "SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData"
    '"SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData WHERE id={id}"
    ConnDB()
    'myCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySql, myConnection)
    'myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim studentID As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(tbStudentID2.Text, studentID) Then
        ' Not a valid ID
        tbDays.Text = String.Empty
    Else
        Using command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT DateDiff('d', [DateofRank], [currentDate]) FROM StudentData WHERE StudentID = @StudentID", myConnection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentID)

            ConnDB()

            Dim days As Object = command.ExecuteScalar()
            tbDays.Text = If(Convert.IsDBNull(days), String.Empty, Convert.ToString(days))
        End Using


        ' ADD PARAMETERS - ORDER MATTERS !!!
        Access.AddParam("@TIG", tbDays.Text)
        Access.AddParam("@SID", tbStudentID2.Text)

        ' RUN COMMAND
        Access.ExecQuery("UPDATE StudentData " &
                         "SET TimeinGrade=@TIG " &
                         "WHERE StudentID=@SID")

        ' REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
        If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```